# I can't upgrade php 5.4 to 7 in centos server

Tags: php, centos7

I follow the tutorial given in https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/php7. I complete all instructions. But, finally `phpinfo()` shows php version 5.4 instead of 7.

Comment: Did you restart `php-fpm` service?

Comment: restart apache and check once

Comment: Provide your configs.

Comment: @zerkms if you mention the file name it would be easy to me. (e.g., `/etc/httpd/conf/...`)

Comment: Everything you touched, it would save time.

Comment: it is updated now. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @zerkms It should be deleted. ok?

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting your apache , as this is not mentioned in tutorial

```
 systemctl restart httpd.service
```