# Is the official release of php 7 in CentOS released?

Tags: php, centos7

In this 2 years old tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7) they said

> Since PHP 7.x is not yet packaged in official repositories for the major distributions, we'll have to rely on a third-party source.

But, In the [centos wiki](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7) they talked about official release as I guessed. But I am bit confused whether it is official release or not. Although I follow the wiki instruction but my php don't upgraded([I cann't upgrade php 5.4 to 7 in centos server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921037/i-cannt-update-php-5-4-to-7-in-centos-server)).

Comment: That article's two years old, and was written only about a month after PHP 7's release. Chances are it's outdated.

Comment: @ceejayoz I also noticed that that is 2 years old. But why they don't update the article?

Comment: @ceejayoz Does cenos wiki talk about official release?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove 5.x and install 7.x with yum - it cannot be updated.

For 7.2 you have to enable a special repository.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-php-7-2-on-centos-7-rhel-7/

Comment: May be you answer on another of my question. See question again.